# How do I get the Inifere's Madness ability?

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

Inifere talks to me in the Calm, and I have clicked through all the conversation options, but there is no option for the bound/link connection to receive the ability [Inifere's Madness](https://tormenttidesofnumenera.wiki.fextralife.com/Inifere's+Madness) from him.

Is there something I should have done or said to him during the Endless Horror quest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make a connection with him after I reached tier 4.

I visited the Calm many times during tier 3, and as soon as I levelled up to tier 4, I was able to connect with him.

So, my take is: I get a limited amount of connections per tier. At tier 4, you get 4 links.